# How to use cross entropy loss in tensorFlow when training on TPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tpu

I am trying to train transformer encoder (from here - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer) on TPU:

```
def test():
    train_step_signature = [
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
    ]
    @tf.function(input_signature=train_step_signature)
    def train_step(inp, tar):
      with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = transf(inp,  
                                     True, 
                                     None, 
                                     None, 
                                     None)
        loss = loss_function(tar, predictions) # <- error is here
                                               # I use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

    vocabsize=1000
    transf = Transformer(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff,
                              vocabsize, vocabsize, 
                              pe_input=vocabsize, 
                              pe_target=vocabsize,
                              rate=dropout_rate)
    for iter in range(1,75000):
      print(iter)
      inp=np.random.randint(vocabsize, size=(5,11))
      tar=np.random.randint(vocabsize, size=(5,11))
      train_step(inp,tar)
```

It works on CPU. But after ~100 iterations on TPU I get an error when calling loss_function (marked above):

> InvalidArgumentError:
>
> Function invoked by the following node is not compilable: {{node __inference_train_step_4179}} = __inference_train_step_4179[_XlaMustCompile=true, config_proto="\n\007\n\003GPU\020\000\n\007\n\003CPU\020\0012\002J\0008\001", executor_type=""](dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input, dummy_input...
>
> Uncompilable nodes:
> sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Const:
>
> unsupported op: Const op with type DT_STRING is not supported by XLA.
>
> Stacktrace:         Node: __inference_train_step_4179, function:        Node:
> sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Const, function: __inference_train_step_4179
> ...

As far as I understand - the error is caused by assertion within loss function which is not supported by Xla.
What can I do here ?